# find the user who is trying to create a directory

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu, permission-denied, cakephp-bake

Hello I am using cakePHP's bake console to create a cakePHP application. But when I run the scripts, it says that the present user does not have permission to create a folder in the directory. So to find out the user who is being denied, I echoed `whoami` from the PHP script, and got the user. Now I made that user the owner of the directory. And as a check I even created folders on that directory from the terminal. But when the script runs via PHP, it spits the error on the terminal saying the user does not have permission.

What could the problem be?

Comment: To clarify, the error occurs when you try running the pages through your browser, right?

Comment: yes! I am using a browser to print the present user using "echo `whoami`;". And I am making that user the owner for that directory, temporarily.

Comment: why not give everyone access to the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu, ensure that the owner and group of the folders are both `www-data`. During the development phase, I also tend to make the permissions 777 or 755.